# How to send value with AJAX type GET?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm pretty new at Ajax. I want to send data with AJAX without FORM. I tried the `<a>` but it did not work. Some things may be missing in the example. Everything works, but the value is not sent.

HTML & PHP Code

```
<?php
$mail = $_GET['mail'];
$lists = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM customers WHERE mail='$mail'"); 
while($list = mysql_fetch_array($lists))
{
    $id = $list['id'];
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$id.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">
                <a id="delete" value="'.$id.'" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Delete This">
                    <span class="table-icon">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-close"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
?>
<div class="mdl" id="alertmodal"><div class="mdl-container"><div class="postMessage" align="center"></div></div><div class="mdl-close" data-target="#alertmodal"></div></div>
<a class="btn" id="confirm" data-type="confirm" data-fullscreen="false" data-overlayClick="true"></a>
```

Ajax Code

```
$(function(){
    $(".mdl-close").on('click',function(){
        mdl_close("#alertmodal");
        window.location.href = 'delete.php';
    });
    $('#confirm').mdl({
        content:"Are you sure?" 
    }, function(result){
        if(result==true)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'deletethis.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {id: $('#delete').val(),},
                success: function(result){
                    $(".postMessage").html(result.Message);
                    mdl_open("#alertmodal");
                }
            });
        }

    });
    $("#delete").on('click',function(e) {
        $( "#confirm" ).trigger( "click" );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

What can I use outside of `<a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replase `data: {id: $('#delete').val(),},` to `data: {id: $('#delete').attr('value'),},`.